# How to seperate the background image from a grid in css

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, css-grid

I'm trying to transform on hover, the background image that is in a grid. I don't know how to organise my classes so that I can scale the image and not the grid block.

I have this code:

```
.useful-link1 {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    grid-column: 2/4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/nasa.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: 40%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.useful-link1:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

How would I go about taking the background image out? I know it's an elementary question, not so easy to search for apparently, though.

Comment: You'll probably want to add the `:hover` to the div and not to a link within the div. It's hard to say, though, since you did not include your HTML. Please update your questions with more context, and/or a working demo.

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nem6v1qb/)?

Comment: @DavidThomas or like this for better performance https://jsfiddle.net/nem6v1qb/3/

Comment: @Temani: so many ways, but until Jay responds I'm still not quite sure what he wants.

Comment: @DavidThomas I am pretty sure we want this .. you will get a thank you soon :p

Comment: Indeed you will :) Such a subtle thing to do that opens up possibilities. Thanks for your help everyone. @DavidThomas, Bill Murray is watching you.

Comment: @TemaniAfif why does that give better performance, it looks like it's over complicated. Is it worth it?

Comment: when using transform you will not trigger re-painting (https://csstriggers.com/transform) unlike background (https://csstriggers.com/background-size) so there is a clear difference of performance when doing transition

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif, something new for me to consider. Enjoy your day.